# Command Cooldown discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have been working on updating my current command cooldown, when upadting my message.js file the cooldown does not show.

This is the current code in the command cooldown file

```
const botconfig  = require("../../botconfig.json");
const fs = require("fs")
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const cooldowns = new Map()
module.exports = async (bot, message) => { 
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
  let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("././prefixes.json", "utf8"))
  
  if(!prefixes[message.guild.id]){
    prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
      prefixes: botconfig.prefix
    };
  }
  
  let prefix = prefixes[message.guild.id].prefixes;

    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd))
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args)

    if(!cooldowns.has(commandfile.name)){
      cooldowns.set(commandfile.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(commandfile.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (commandfile.cooldown) * 1000;

    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
      const experation_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;
      if (current_time < experation_time){
        const time_left = (experation_time - current_time) / 1000;
        return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using this command!`)
      }
    }

    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
    
}
```

In the command file I have

```
module.exports = {
  config:{
    name: "beg",
    aliases: [],
    cooldown: 5, // current cooldown in seconds
    category: "currency",
    description: "Gets you money",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
    accessableby: "Members"
  },
```

When I use the command the command will work but the cooldown does not work and lets me use the command again. Am I doing something wrong? I would also like to know if I stop running the bot for an update will the cooldown save for example I use the command "!!daily" then re-set the bot for an update and 24 hours did not pass that when it goes back online the cooldown save's and keeps counting.

Comment: Why do you have multiple checks inside of your first code that's encapsulated in a module? Why not just set it as the default client that's tracking the messages like the [discord.js guide recommends](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cooldown should be a Discord.Collection

```js
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection(); //that goes on top of your script
```

Is first time what I comment here, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Discord.Collection is extending Map, it does not add a whole lot that is important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of order:

First you call     `if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args)` but then only you check if the Cooldown exists. You need to rearange you code like this, move the `.run` down.

```
const botconfig  = require("../../botconfig.json");
const fs = require("fs")
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
// While this does not matter, we make a Collection to for consistentcy
module.exports = async (bot, message) => { 
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("././prefixes.json", "utf8"))

    if(!prefixes[message.guild.id]){
            prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
                    prefixes: botconfig.prefix
            };
    }
  
    let prefix = prefixes[message.guild.id].prefixes;

    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
    if(!commandfile) return; 
    // return if no command Found, if one is found, proceed to check for cooldown

    if(!cooldowns.has(commandfile.name)){
      cooldowns.set(commandfile.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(commandfile.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (commandfile.cooldown) * 1000;

    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
            const experation_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;
            if (current_time < experation_time){
                    const time_left = (experation_time - current_time) / 1000;
                    return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using this command!`);
            }
    }
    // above here is the return, if the cooldown is still active, if so it returns with the message
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    // here we set the time_stamp and now can run the command
    commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
}
```